# How do I make a fast gaussian blur in PHP?

Tags: php, image

I am trying to apply a gaussian blur effect to images using PHP. However, the script, as included below, takes very long to execute, especially with large images. Is there any way to "bring in" a highly compressed (loss of quality is okay) image to blur, then blurring it, and then outputting that, without saving the compressed image at any time?

```html
<?

$image = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");

for ($i = 0; $i < 250; $i++) {

 imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);

}
  
header("content-type: image/png");

imagepng($image);

imagedestroy($image);

?>
```

Comment: Is Imagick out of the question on your server platform?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261869/php-implementation-of-stackblur-algorithm-available/20264482#20264482)